# Building and training a logistic regression network with two inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

The task is to build a NN that could accept two images from the MNIST dataset and say if the images contain the same numbers. The NN architecture is as follows:

```
input_1 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 \
                                            => 10 -> logistic_output
input_2 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 -> 100 /
```

'inputs' are 28x28 images, 'logistic' classifies same/not and 'numbers' represent hidden units.
The problem is that fitting accuracy is < 50% (expect > 90%) with my current solution:

```
in_1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
out_1 = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape)(in_1)
for i in range(0, n_layers):
    out_1 = keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden, activation='relu')(out_1)

in_2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
out_2 = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape)(in_2)
for i in range(0, n_layers):
    out_2 = keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden, activation='relu')(out_2)

concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([out_1, out_2])
post_concat = keras.layers.Dense(n_post_concat,  activation='relu')(concat)
logistic_out = keras.layers.Dense(n_output, activation='sigmoid')(post_concat)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[in_1, in_2], outputs=[logistic_out])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-1),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X_train_1, X_train_2], y_train_match, 
                validation_data=([X_valid_1, X_valid_2], y_valid_match))
```

p.s. `relu` layers have `kernel_initializer='he_normal'` (dropped for clarity), `n_layers=5`, `input_shape`=(28, 28), `n_hidden=100`, `n_post_concat=10`, `n_output=1`; the input data has been checked for correctness and has equal amounts of matched (1) and unmatched (0) images.

Comment: Instead of using Dense layers try using Conv2D layers, they work better with images and you can also add some regularization layers. If changing the NN architecture is an option then try training only a single CNN on MNIST data, pass both images one by one, and then compare the outputs. If both outputs are same them both images also have same number.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the exercise 10 from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/11_deep_learning.ipynb but thanks for the suggestion.